# Recommended flexible website solution?

Tags: static

My site has a MyBB forums installation, and that is pretty much all I need. Forums.

However, I need a homepage and a couple other static pages, for showing relevant information, links, etc.

I don't need something fancy, all I need is something very flexible regarding theme and style editing, and just a couple simple modules, like public polls. That's all.

I am very graphical, and I am looking for something to let me edit pretty much every aspect of the site. These are static pages, mainly, so I don't need something very complex.

Some people tell me to use Dreamweaver, but quite honestly, that is not what I am looking for, even thought it does offer a lot of flexibility.

I want something like, you know, Drupal or.. some other simple, deeply-editable in terms of graphics and style web platform.

What would you recommend to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it the simple way, use WordPress, you should be able to just about everything you need with it. Then you can keep using myBB as before.

Answer (score 2):

You might find that simple static HTML pages with a widget included for the public polls is quicker to code, maintain and run.

If all you are planning to do is add 2 or 3 static pages then you add a big performance overhead, ongoing maintenance requirements, more potential for hacking, and your site will be slower.